# Android, Java: Resized Bitmap ignores bitmap options

Tags: java, android, bitmap, resize

I am creating this Android game with Java. However, I load the bitmaps and then resize them to fit screens and such (dpi isn't really exact). BUT my thought is also to load the bitmaps in 16b (mBitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444) for devices with a small amount of ram. But when I resize the bitmaps they seem to go back to 32b (Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).

This is how I declare the options:

```
    mBitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    mBitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
```

This is how I load the bitmaps:

```
    mBitmaps.add(getResizedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, imagePath, mBitmapOptions)));
```

And this is the getResizeBitmap method:

```
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm) 
    {
                    //Original size
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();

                    //New size (percent)
        float newWidth = 1 * mScaleWidth;
        float newHeight = 1 * mScaleHeight;

                    //Create the matrix
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(newWidth, newHeight);

                    //Recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

                    //Recycle the old Bitmap
        bm.recycle();

        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Any ideas why the new Bitmap ignores the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the [createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) method? It should preserve the options. In your case, you are creating a completely new Bitmap and it probably applies a default config.

EDIT: Another option would be to use your code and add a call to the [copy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy%28android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean%29) method like this:

```
Bitmap smallerBitmap = resizedBitmap.copy (Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, false);
resizedBitmap.recycle ();
```

However, I don't think this will have a nice performance...

Comment: That was my thought and I have seen that some methods accepts a Config as parameter but I can't figure out how to apply it with the other paramaters that I need. Can you please tell me how?

Comment: I did resize that way before I think but the quality of the Bitmap dropped ALOT. But scaling it with the matrix it didn't.

Comment: No problem. Does it get slower due to the copying?

Comment: I load all bitmaps that I'm going to use in a loadingscreen and it isn't notable slower.